# Angular timer works when I inspect the element in IE browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, settimeout, intervals

I'm using $interval function to show the popup after everything is loaded.

```
 timer = $interval(function () {
            OpenpopUp(uiService);
            return false;
        }, 4000, 1);
```

but this popup works only when I inspect the element in IE browser, In google chrome it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are using `$interval` to perform this action only once (because you have specified the third parameter as 1, which is the number of times the timer should run). The `$timeout` will be a better option for this action. Also why are you doing `return false;` seems like its not needed.

Can you check whether implementing the below solution solves your issue?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
  timer = $timeout(function() {
    //OpenpopUp(uiService);
    console.log("timer works");
  }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">

</div>
```